# Broken JavaScript after concatening assets with autoptimize

Tags: javascript, wordpress, concatenation, minify

I installed the autoptimize plugin in WordPress in order to concatenate and minify my assets. Everything seems to be unhindered, except for the following code, which does not appear to execute:

```
// Fade image
if ($('.fadein-page-banner') != null) {
    $('.fadein-page-banner img').on("load", function () { 
        $('#video-loading-icon').css('opacity', 0);
        $('.fadein-page-banner-wrapper').addClass('fadeout-behind');
        $('.fadein-page-banner').addClass('fade-in-out'); 
    });
}
```

This is not in a document.ready block. I tried that, too, but it did not work. The containers never get the classes added to them. I also tried removing the if condition. The code works fine when I turn off the optimizations for javascript code, but it would be nice to have...

Comment: WordPress loads jQuery in no-conflict mode, which means that you cannot access jQuery with the `$` like you have.  IF you would like to keep it with the `$`  (which I do), then wrap it in a "no-conflict-safe" document ready, which looks like: `jQuery(function($) {...your code above...});`.  Then it should work.

Comment: Or enclose it in small module `(function($) { /* your code */ } )(jQuery)` and you can use `$` freely.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I don't think it made a difference anyway, haha.

Answer (score 0):

try excluding `js/jquery/jquery.js` from JS optimization. if that does not work, check what your browser's console has to say about javascript errors.